# cambiar de color el input cuando presiones un tecla

Tags: javascript

tengo 5 input a los cuales solo se le puede ingresar un numero del 1 al 3 
cuando presiono 1 sale rojo, 2 amarillo y 3 verde lo pude hacer con el primer input 
lo que no quiero es hacer una funcion para cada input ya que tendria 5 scripts
esta es mi funcion de js
function validar_prioridad(){
        var elem1   =   document.getElementById("prioridad1");

```
    // ...
    if(elem1.value==="1"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "#FA5D60";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value==="2"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value==="3"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "#02FC73";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value===""){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "";
        return;
    }
    // ...
    // enviamos el formulario
```

}

lo que quiero es una funcion global por asi decirlo para llamarla en cada uno de input y no tener los 5 scripts

Comment: Te ha funcionado alguna de las respuestas?

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de esta manera, solo es llamar la función en cada uno de los inputs y colocarle un evento que lo desencadene, en este caso es con un `onkeyup` y enviarle el nombre del **id** del input

```js
function cambiadecolor(id){
  var elem1 = document.getElementById(id);
  
    if(elem1.value==="1"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "#FA5D60";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value==="2"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value==="3"){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "#02FC73";
        return;
    }
    else if(elem1.value===""){
        elem1.style.backgroundColor = "";
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="cambiadecolor('uno')" id="uno" placeholder="uno"><br>
<input type="text" onkeyup="cambiadecolor('dos')" id="dos" placeholder="dos"><br>
<input type="text" onkeyup="cambiadecolor('tres')" id="tres" placeholder="tres"><br>
<input type="text" onkeyup="cambiadecolor('cuatro')" id="cuatro" placeholder="cuatro"><br>
<input type="text" onkeyup="cambiadecolor('cinco')" id="cinco" placeholder="cinco">
```

Comment: muchas gracias se me hizo muy sencillo ese metodo

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría usar jquery, aunque no lo indicas te lo paso en ese formato, dado que me parece mucho mas sencillo y cómodo para lo que quieres.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('input').keyup(function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        switch(valor) {
          case "1":
            $(this).css('background','red');
            break;
          case "2":
            $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
            break;
          case "3":
            $(this).css('background', 'green');
            break;
          case "":
             $(this).css('background', 'none');
            break;
        }
      });
    });
```

Si agregas tu librerias de jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y pegas seguidamente este script lo tienes.

Lo que hace es que cuando el documento esté cargado selecciona todos los inputs y escucha por el evento keyup. Si existe, selecciona el valor del input donde se dio y comprueba que el valor coincida con alguno de los case. Si es así hace lo que marca.

Aquí funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/Emerita/60315oby/15/

Comment: disculpen la demora ,muchas gracias me ayudo mucho